# Java - Build and run eclipse project from command line

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project written using eclipse ide and I want to run it through ssh on a different machine, but I have to do this using the command line and I don't know exactly how.

I am a beginner at both shell commands and java.

Could you please give me a useful link with answers regarding this question, or perhaps a set instructions of how to do this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Maven or Ant are the best option but for an **Eclipse-only** solution
you can choose **File -> Export** and select **Java -> Runnable JAR File**
then transfer the *JAR file* to your other machine and run this from the command line:

```
java -jar YOUR.JAR
```

Comment: can you do it without JAR - ing?

Comment: You can but you would have to copy the contents of the bin directory and any libraries your program uses to your other machine and include them all on your classpath (see xappymah's answer).

Comment: Great answer, but my problem is that I want to run that jar on a machine that has an older JRE. To do this, under Eclipse preferences I set the compiler compliance level to `1.6` and I create the jar.. but this doesnt solve the problem. Any clue?

Comment: @Alphaaa: Probably best to ask this as a separate question with more detail - I'm sure you'll get an answer.

Comment: how the hell is this supposed to be building an eclipse project from CLI -_-

Comment: @nonchip: The question is how to create a build that can be run using a CLI, not how to build from a CLI.

Comment: @RussHayward the question is literally titled "build and run" from CLI.

Answer (score 34):

You can run Java applications from the command line.
The simplified syntax looks like this:

```
java -cp <classpath> <main class> <args>
```

where:

`<classpath>` - list of directories and/or JAR-files where needed classes reside separated by ";" for Windows or ":" for linux (default classpath is "." - the current directory);

`<main class>` - fully qualified name of the class containig main() method (for example, org.myself.HelloWorld)

`<args>` - various arguments for application if any.

So, if you find the directory where Eclipse stored compiled classes (usually it's bin) you may use the command, like

```
java -cp . my.package.MyClass
```

Or, if you use some libraries and classes in other directories, it could be:

```
java -cp some-cool-lib.jar:another-lib.jar:/some/directory/with/classes my.package.MyClass
```

Comment: "very easy" looks different

Comment: With other libraries and classes, the command should use ; (semicolon), not : (colon). So, it should be `java -cp some-cool-lib.jar;another-lib.jar;/some/directory/with/classes my.package.MyClass`; otherwise, it will say cannot find the main class.

Comment: Semicolon is used on Windows as it was mentioned in my answer. On Linux and MacOS you have to use colon.

Answer (score 3):

To build and run a Java project, Its good to use an ant or maven tool. you can find many tutorials on google for the same.

a good tutorial on ant is here http://www.intranetjournal.com/java-ant/

Comment: isn't there a way of doing this without any additional tools? doesn't eclipse provide some commands for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did and it worked for me. Hope it could help. 
[image]