# Trying to build/run java program from cmd line with external library

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I am trying to run a java program from the cmd line but I have an external library, as per below:
[image]

I have tried the advice from this previous question ([Java - Build and run eclipse project from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441565/java-build-and-run-eclipse-project-from-command-line/24396335)), like this:

```
java -cp <classpath> <main class> <args>
```

In my case (with response):

```
java -cp "ejml-v0.34-libs/*" MatrixServer
Error: Could not find or load main class MatrixServer.java
```

I may be confused as how to run my  file and the path to it?

When I try and run the java file normally with javac then java, it has issues referencing the external 'ejml' library. I'm just looking for an easy way to run it form the cmd line!

Comment: That only puts the jars located in ejml-v0.34-libs/ in the classpath. But the directory containing your own classes must also be in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java -cp "ejml-v0.34-libs/*;." MatrixServer
```

. to include your current directory(where compiled files are located ) along with ejml-v0.34-libs folder.

`<classpath>` - list of directories and/or JAR-files where needed classes reside separated by ";" for Windows or ":" for linux (default classpath is "." - the current directory);