# Appium test not able to run through terminal(Programming language used is Java)

Tags: java, android, appium

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYPZ5.png) [Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbCVH.png) Have written Appium test for android using Java as programming language I'm able to compile and run the scripts using IDE but when I try to compile and run through terminal I'm getting the error.

Comment: Mind sharing the code or being a little more specific? Thanks!

Comment: @BlessAnime Have Created an image of the code please have a look Thanks

Comment: you must upload error log too. Have you start your appium server? you must start your appium server manually or programatically. In your code you just only initialize DesiredCapabilites and AppiumDriver.

Comment: @SubanDhyako Have added error Log and I have started appium Server when I run my script in IDE it is working fine but I'm getting the errors only when I run from terminal Thanks

Comment: how did you try to run your code? you must tell what you want, what have to done, error logs, what is not working... while you ask problem.

Comment: @SubanDhyako I'm able to run the code using IntelliJ IDE. But when I try to run using the terminal I'm getting the errors. You can see the Code in "Code Image" attachment and Errors logs in "Error Log" attachment

Comment: In order to run your appium project, you cannot just compile one file and run it. you need to build the entire project i.e. make executable jar file of your project.  [Build and run eclipse project from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441565/java-build-and-run-eclipse-project-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

you have not added the jar files, which required to run successfully your appium project kindly request to add the jar files you required how to add?

Right click on the project  -> Properties -> java Build Path -> Libraries

in libraries -> Add external JARS you can click the button and add the jar file which you needed you need mostly two jar file

1. Selenium Server Standalone
2. Java Client

I have shared the link with you for reference to more infomation

https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-appium.html

Comment: I have attached the jar files of Selenium Server Standalone

Java Client

Comment: then also you having the same issue